# Difference between "hypotyposis", "ekphrasis" and "iconotext"

Tags: differences, nouns, rhetoric

What is the difference between *hypotyposis*, *ekphrasis* and *iconotext*?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please explain the reason you are asking and share your research on the question. As it stands this question is incomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are all "figures of vivid description"—and you can find out more details about them from a rhetoric resource like [this one](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/).

Comment: And [this one](http://www.oocities.org/s_awung/text.pdf), which distinguishes *iconotext* from *ekphrasis*